# Auto git fetch when the Android studio (IntelliJ) is idle

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I usually use `Git Fetch` to have the latest information from the server.`Git Fetch` won't change the code base and its not take much time and network traffic. So when I go toilet or do something else it would be good to auto do `Git Fetch`. Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling an [automatic fetch in IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206810905-Enabling-automatic-Git-Fetch) was asked before.

See [issue IDEA-24057](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24057) and [IDEA-100846](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100846)

Check out [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox): It has auto fetch functionality.
That feature does not seem to be available in native IntelliJ alone (ie: you need to find a third-party plugin)

> It would indeed be nice if this would work because the configuration options in File | Settings | Version Control | Background are now ignored for GIT and this doesn't seem to be indicated in the UI or help.
>
> Also, people coming from Atlassian SourceTree expect this to happen automatically. This messes up merging remote branches because those remote branches are not up to date automatically (something SourceTree users are used to).
> This hampers (full) adoption of IDEA.